# Best method for creating a responsive website in React

Tags: reactjs

As I learned more about website design and React, I wanted to move away from using the bootstrap library to create responsive websites. But I was wondering what are the other great alternative ways to have a responsive websites- not only in changing the layout but also the type of components being rendered.

Let's say for a weather website, I would like to display a full graphics components with weather details (which includes graphical images with data) in desktop while in mobile version I would like to simply display the relevant data to pass the information in the possible given space. What's the best method to be undertaken in react?

Comment: CSS media queries and CSS flex can go a long way in term of responsiveness. In term of layout, I really like CSS grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-router offers a Responsive Routing feature and their docs are very straightforward. I have yet to use this myself but want to on my next project.
[react-training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

Comment: That's interesting! I am seeing it for the first time too! You deserve my bounty!